# Null Pointer Exception in custom component's getStyle

Tags: apache-flex, module, nullpointerexception

when running my application I get this strange error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mx.core::UIComponent/getStyle()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:11104]
at mx.core::UIComponent/getConstraintValue()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9073]
at mx.core::UIComponent/get horizontalCenter()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9242]
at spark.layouts::BasicLayout/measure()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\BasicLayout.as:253]
at spark.components.supportClasses::GroupBase/measure()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\GroupBase.as:1148]
at mx.core::UIComponent/measureSizes()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8496]
at mx.core::UIComponent/validateSize()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8420]
at spark.components::Group/validateSize()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1012]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateSize()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:665]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:816]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

It happens within my custom component (which doesn't mess with styles or anything), **only if** I load this part of an application as a module. The _nonInheritingStyles property is set to null, which looks like wrong component initialization. Any guesses? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem -- only in 4.6.  Flex 4.5 worked fine. I think it's due to a change in the way ModuleInfo handles loading.  The Preloader tries to resolve a bunch of graphics calls, but since the parent has no graphics components established, the calls break. (Even if you protect getStyle() with an override and a try-catch around the super.getStyle() call, other graphics calls will break.)

WORKAROUND: If I add a component to my top-level mxml (the Application subclass), the problem goes away.   I used

<s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0"/>

It would be good to know the lightest-weight component that will work here.

I'm guessing the Preloader is expecting at least a splash screen in place before the first module is loaded. Otherwise it is just a Flex bug.